# Stripe test on React & Express returns 404, also does not console.log req.body

Tags: reactjs, express, http-status-code-404, stripe-payments

I'm learning how to integrate Stripe into React & Express. I'm getting a 404 error. Also, when I try to console.log the req.body, nothing appears.

on payment button click Expecting "Purchase Complete", getting "Purchase Error" (below)

```
async submit(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let { token } = await this.props.stripe.createToken();
    let response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/charge", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" },
        body: token.id
    });

    if (response.ok) {
        console.log("Purchase Complete")
        this.setState({ complete: true })
    } else {
        console.log("Purchase Error")
        console.log(response)
    }
}
```

router:

```
router.post("/charge", async (req, res) => {

  console.log("req.body: ", req.body)

  try {
    let { status } = await stripe.charges.create({
      amount: 14,
      currency: "usd",
      description: "Purchase 1,000 followers",
      source: req.body
    });
    res.json({ status });
 } catch (err) {
   res.status(500).end();
 }
});
```

Expecting to see req.body in console (from above code) but getting nothing. I've tried adding forms of bodyParser in server/src/index.js (below).

```
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```